# EnterpriseDeviceManager cannot be applied to given types

Tags: android

I have the same issue as here:

https://seap.samsung.com/forum-topic/problem-arises-here-getsystemserviceenterprisedevicemanagerenterprisepolicyservice

I followed the instructions on the link above and “EnterpriseDeviceManager cannot be applied to given types” is displayed.

Do I need to change my gradle or manifest?

```
package com.test.myapplication;
```

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.samsung.android.knox.EnterpriseDeviceManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

EnterpriseDeviceManager edm = new EnterpriseDeviceManager(this);
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation files('libs/knoxsdk.jar')
implementation files('libs/supportlib.jar')
implementation files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
```

}

Comment: We don't know what you should change because you didn't show us anything you did.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for responding. 

package com.test.myapplication;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.samsung.android.knox.EnterpriseDeviceManager;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    EnterpriseDeviceManager edm = new EnterpriseDeviceManager(this);
}

Comment: Post your code in the question and format it correctly. That comment is not readable. You also need to describe the problem and error, not just give some random link.

Comment: Sorry, I’m still working out how to use this site.
package com.test.myapplication;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.samsung.android.knox.EnterpriseDeviceManager;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    EnterpriseDeviceManager edm = new EnterpriseDeviceManager(this);
}

Comment: All you did was put the code in a new comment. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49140848/edit) your question to add code. (That's a link for you - there's an edit link below your question)

Comment: package com.test.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.samsung.android.knox.EnterpriseDeviceManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    EnterpriseDeviceManager edm = new EnterpriseDeviceManager(this);

}

Comment: I'm flagging the question as "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers._"

Comment: I get it. Thanks. I got some code in and then: “Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.” I tried CTRL+K with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.

My Solution :

1. Make sure "knoxsdk.jar" file exists. (samsung knox sdk)
2. File "build.gradle" on dependencies add this > compileOnly files ('libs/knoxsdk.jar')

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this configuration:

```
compileOnly files('libs/knoxsdk.jar')
runtimeOnly files('libs/supportlib.jar')
```